# Problemas con ArrayList en Java: al ordenar y con los datos guardados

Tags: java

Tengo 2 problemas.

**Primero**: ¿Por qué cuando me pide la dimensión y pongo (por ejemplo) 10 y en valor máximo 100 me sale este error?
Siempre que pongo una valor máximo mayor que la dimensión sale pero si es inferior o igual no sale.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 75, Size: 10
> at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
> at Lab01_02.main(Lab01_02.java:29)

**Segundo**: Al ordenar cuando me pide la dimensión pongo: 10 y  en valor máximo pongo 5.
Esto es lo que me imprime.

Sin ordenar: dimensión: 10;
2   1   2   3   4   2   4   3   4   2

Ordenado:   dimensión: 10;
1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2

¿Por qué me cambia los números de mi ArrayList al ordenarlo?

---

La dimensión es el tamaño de mi ArrayList, por ejemplo: si introduzco una dimensión = 10 entonces crearé 10 números con `Math.random()` y los guardaré en el ArrayList.

```
public class L7{

    final static int cap = 10000;
    
    public static void main(String [] args){

        int min = 0, max;
        int index;
        ArrayList <Integer> llista = new ArrayList<Integer>(cap);

        index = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Dimension?"));
        max = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Valor máximo"));

        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){

            llista.add(Integer.valueOf((int)(Math.random()*((max-1)-min + 1) + min)));
        }

        llista.trimToSize();

        int c = 0;

        System.out.println("\nSin ordenar:\t" + llista.size());
        
        for(Integer x : llista){

            System.out.print(llista.get(x) + "\t");
            if(c == 9){
                
                System.out.println();
                c = -1;
            }
            c++;
        }

        Collections.sort(llista, new Comparator<Integer>(){

            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2){

                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });

         c = 0;

        System.out.println("\nOrdenado:\t" + llista.size());
        
        for(Integer x : llista){

            System.out.print(llista.get(x) + "\t");
            if(c == 9){
                
                System.out.println();
                c = -1;
            }
            c++;
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es eso de *dimensión*?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. ¿Qué es eso de _máximo_? Hay cosas que igual das por hecho que las sabemos y no explicas. Estaría bien que vayas explicando lo que haces y que esperas que ocurra

Comment: @Jaeger si la solución te sirvió márcala como "aceptada" con el tick en mi respuesta, para que así quede cerrada y a mas personas les pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Primero

Tu problema está en el siguiente `for` (se repite varias veces):

```
for(Integer x : llista){
    System.out.print(llista.get(x) + "\t");
}
```

`X` es el valor de cada elemento de tu ArrayList, y sabiendo que son números aleatorios. Puede coincidir (cuando el `max` es mayor que la `dimension`) con que te genere un numero aleatorio mayor que la `dimensión` de tu `ArrayList`. Por lo que al intentar acceder a esa posición te de el `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
llista.get(x)
```

Ademas que no tiene sentido que hagas un `foreach` para despues acceder mediante el `index` dentro del `for`.

Por lo que tu `for` debería de ser:

```
for(Integer x : llista){
    System.out.print(x + "\t");
}
```

o

```
for(int x = 0;x<llista.size();x++){
    System.out.print(llista.get(x) + "\t");
}
```

### Segundo:

Tu segundo problema es por que estas creando un nuevo `ArrayList`, creo que ademas estas intentando comprobar que valor es el menor para quedarte con el.

Si solo quieres ordenarlo:

```
Collections.sort(llista);
```